# INSERT INTO tbl_1 with data from tbl_2 with a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I need to copy some data from one table to another but I need to use a WHERE clause in order to have it all work properly.

`tbl_1` has `classID` `vendorID` `category_id` (**EDIT: category_id is currently empty, this is what I'm trying to copy from the other table...**) and `departmentID`

`tbl_2` has `class_code` `department_id` and `category_id`

I want to grab the `category_id` in `tbl_2` and put it into `tbl_1` where the `tbl_1.classID = tbl_2.class_code` AND `tbl_1.departmentID = tbl_2.department_id`

I tried using:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_1
SELECT tbl_2.gateway_id
FROM tbl_2
WHERE tbl_1.classID = tbl_2.class_code 
AND tbl_1.departmentID = tbl_2.department_id
```

But, no luck. I get an error 'Unknown column tbl_1.classID in WHERE clause'

Should I be using `UPDATE` or something like that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If `tbl_1` is empty, how do you expect `tbl_1.classID = tbl_2.class_code` to return anything?

Comment: @All, my apologies. `tbl_1.category_id` is empty, not the entire `tbl_1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for a [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) to update existing rows in `tbl_1` with the correct `category_id` taken from `tbl_2`, not a `INSERT` which will add rows to `tbl_1`

```
UPDATE tbl_1 JOIN tbl_2 ON 
    tbl_1.classID = tbl_2.class_code 
    AND tbl_1.departmentID = tbl_2.department_id
SET tbl_1.category_id = tbl_2.category_id
```

Comment: That was the fix! Thank you! Simple, elegant and it worked, gotta love that.

Answer (score 2):

Your insert statement should specify which columns the data is being inserted into, and the select needs to specify that you're also selecting from `tbl_1`. See the [`INSERT...SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) page in the MySQL manual.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_1 (classID, departmentID)
    SELECT tbl_1.classID, tbl_1.class_code, tbl_2.gateway_id
    FROM tbl_1
    RIGHT JOIN tbl_2 ON tbl_2.class_code = tbl_1.classID
    WHERE tbl_1.departmentID = tbl_2.department_id
```

Obviously, you'll want to fix this to work with your specific example.

Comment: he told that tbl_1 is empty. left join would fail

Comment: @ultor - good point. I think a right join would fix here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I've updated the post. tbl1.category_id is empty. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps you:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_1 (classID, vendorID, category_id, departmentID)
values
(
SELECT tbl_2.class_code, tbl_2.gateway_id, tbl_2.category_id, tbl_2.department_id
FROM tbl_2
)
```